# How to change Warsaw theme's frametitle height in Latex?

Tags: latex

I am making some changes in Warsaw theme. I want to increase the height of the frametitle. I have used the following code, because I did not want the navigation part from the the headline. Now I need to increase the height of the frame title without increasing the font size. Please see the commands I used:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0 ex,dp=0ex]{palette quaternary}%
   
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify if you want to increase the height of the headline (that's the area with the section navigation) or the height of the frametitle (and if yes shall only the box be larger or should also the font size be increased)

Comment: I edit the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust the frametitle template. I marked the line to change with `% <-`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \vspace{2cm}% <- change here to whatever you want
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\strut\insertframetitle\strut\par%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty\else%
            {\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0pt}{0pt}{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
  \nointerlineskip
    \vskip-0.2pt
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
    \vskip-2pt
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{title}
    
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked very well thanks! Do you also have idea how do I change the color of these footline and headline?

Comment: @BAydn Please use the "Ask Question" button if you have a new question

Comment: I used the following and it solved the problem. I guess no need to ask new question. ` \usecolortheme{whale}
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{98, 193, 237}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=blue!90!black}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=blue!0!blue,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{section in foot}{fg=blue, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{subsection in foot}{fg=blue, bg=blue} `